# How is Deno startup fast without running the TypeScript compiler in "watch" mode

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api, deno

As far as I can tell, Deno always compiles TypeScript to JS on startup, and has no "watch" mode.
It's also my understanding that there is no such thing as "incremental compilation" for TypeScript aside from TS watch mode. So that, if one wants fast TS compilation, one must use watch mode.

So I would expect that Deno has a watch mode. But it doesn't. So how is TS compilation fast for Deno?

Note: I know Deno uses a V8 snapshot of tsc so that the tsc starts quickly, but for a large TS project startup time of tsc will be dwarfed by actual compilation time. So I'm not asking about the V8 snapshoting, I'm asking what other tricks Deno uses. Does it use a build daemon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deno caches on disk transpiled output from TypeScript and uses that on subsequent requests for modules if the local source file has not changed (or lack of a `--reload` flag for remote modules).

As of Deno 0.2.8, the TypeScript is lazily instantiated when a TypeScript module needs to be transpiled.  Deno transpiles module by module, instead of a whole project, and caches the results of each individual module.  So when just making a change to a single file, only that module is transpiled.

Because of this single file approach it does mean that you can sometimes run into runtime errors that would have been caught by the TypeScript compiler.  If you want to ensure that your programme is entirely consistent from a type perspective, using `--recompile` will cause each module to be recompiled.

Adding watch functionality could be added, but that would be a feature request.  There are significant challenges to dealing with such a feature though, because of the way the runtime environment works.

Comment: So is the expectation that the user is using an IDE to catch type errors?
Also, does this file-by-file approach mean that features that rely on cross-file information (like `const enum`) don't work in Deno?

Comment: > So is the expectation that the user is using an IDE to catch type errors?

Not exactly.  When transpiling TypeScript, the compiler will gather all dependencies and do a `.emitFile()` and log out any diagnostics that have been produced.  This is similiar to how an IDE works with the Language Services anyways, and takes the diagnostic output and underlines the red squiggles.  The Deno compiler caches all the sources it has fetched in memory, so if you are doing several files, it simply just emits each file as they are requested from V8 when injecting the ESM modules.

Comment: `const enum` (and `enum`) work, because the TypeScript compiler has all the information it needs to transpile the file.  The only "risk" at the moment, which we might want to address, is that it does not invalidate the cache of already transpiled modules, so if you changed a `const enum` in file `a.ts` but it is imported into `b.ts` but you haven't changed `b.ts` otherwise, you could end up out of sync.  With a `const enum` `b.ts` would still be using the "hardwired" values, which might be an issue if they were relied upon externally.

Comment: How does Deno handle situations where the incremental compilation gets in a weird state @Kitson? Is there a --clean or --force or something? Given how many times I have to restart the TS Language Server in VS Code, I would be surprised if weird states weren't a problem.

Comment: Again, currently there is no watch mode, so the TypeScript compiler state does not persist.  When started it compiles each TypeScript module it needs to and then does nothing more.  `--recompile` will invalidate the cache and force TypeScript to recompile all modules, irrespective of if the emit is cached.